# Hovering on an external table and highlight line chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, chart.js

I am building a chart with Chart.js (using Angular 2 directive ng2-charts).

I have an external table where each row data reflects the X-axis label of the chart.

I was wondering if it is possible to hover one row of the table and highlight that label on the line chart (e.g. make the tooltip appears)?

The table and the chart are two completely separate HTML elements of course.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @ℊααnd do you have a code example?